# saving in database using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to insert into database while clicking the save button of editInPlace In JQuery. I'm using CakePHP and MYSQL.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What server side technology are you using: php, asp.net, etc., what database, sqlserver, mysql, etc.

Comment: You're not going to get very far. You need to perform a HTTP request which is interpreted by PHP to insert into the database, jQuery wont do it on its own.

Comment: $.ajax() is used ..And now its working good.....

Answer (score 1):

This [NETTUTS article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/asynchronous-comments-with-jquery-and-json/) might help you understand how to send data back to the server via jQuery and JSON to be saved into a MySQL database with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link given below
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/asynchronous-comments-with-jquery-and-json/